# Socket.io does not work with nodejs express render for ejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ejs

I am using ejs for google session, but it doesn't work if two people have different IP addresses.

İmages:
https://wallpaper-style.glitch.me/yuklemeler/image-1618340573425.png
https://wallpaper-style.glitch.me/yuklemeler/image-1618340658797.png

Comment: It's working for me. Can you please follow steps and let me know if you getting any issue on it.
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: It's not a local example so if your files comes from 'https' your node server should also created via https not http, check your console, probably you will see that the socket.io doesn't actually connected :)

Comment: @sedhalsoni I've already added "Embedded Javascript" on it so nothing makes any difference

Comment: @halilcakar konsolda hiç sorun yok. kod üzerinde ejs kaldırıp res.render i res.sendFile yapınca düzeliyor ama boşver projeyi yapmaktan vazgectim.